# Using Round Robin Method in Node Js, How Can I Assigned a Lead to the Next Professional

Tags: mysql, node.js, round-robin

I have a user-professionals table and a leads table. Based on their specialties, I would like to assign leads to the next available professional. Below is the list of tables available for this.

```
professionals
--id 
--firstname
--lastname
```

```
services
--id 
--name
--description
```

```
professional_services
--service_id
--prefessional_id
```

```
leads
--id 
--professional_id
--firstname
--lastname
--email
--phone
```

If a lead comes to the page and submits the lead generation form, selecting one or more of our services, and I have 3 professionals offering those services, I want to assign each lead to the next available professional. So if I get 10 leads that day, they should be assigned respectively as follow:

```
In the leads table, the assignment should be
| id | professional_id |
|----|-----------------|
| 1  | 1               |
-----|-----------------|
| 2  | 2               |
|----|-----------------|
| 3  | 3               |
|----|-----------------|
| 4  | 1               |
-----|-----------------|
| 5  | 2               |
|----|-----------------|
| 6  | 3               |
|----|-----------------|
| 7  | 1               |
-----|-----------------|
| 8  | 2               |
|----|-----------------|
| 9  | 3               |
|----|-----------------|
| 10 | 1               |
|----|-----------------|
```

I know that the polymorphic relationship method can be used to SELECT all professionals who provide the service or services the lead selected when submitting the form. How do I assign the lead to the next and the next and the next professional in Node js and do the circle over and over?

Answer (score 1):

To assign professionals one by one whenever new leads are added, you may perform several operations like this:

First, find out the last `professional_id` assigned to the last lead identified by the highest `id`:

```
SELECT professional_id FROM leads
WHERE professional_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then, find the next `professional_id` by using the last professional_id found by the above query:

```
SELECT professional_id FROM professionals
WHERE professional_id > ?
ORDER BY professional_id LIMIT 1
```

OR

```
SELECT MIN(professional_id) FROM professionals
WHERE professional_id > ?
```

If the above query does not give any result, i.e. the MAX professional ID has been allocated to the last allocated lead, OR, no professionals have been assigned to any leads yet (i.e. this is the first lead), then the first lead will need to be assigned, so find the professional with the MIN ID

```
SELECT MIN(professional_id) FROM professionals
```

Whatever `professional_id` is retrieved, assign that to the next lead (assuming you already know the last lead ID)

```
UPDATE leads SET professional_id = ?
WHERE id = ?
```

If you don't know the last Lead ID, then find it first

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM leads WHERE professional_id IS NULL
```

And then update that record with min lead id and no professional id.